# Is it wise to use jQuery for whitelisting tags? Are there existing solutions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fckeditor, whitelist

### My problem

I want to clean HTML pasted in a rich text editor (FCK 1.6 at the moment). The cleaning should be based on a whitelist of tags (and perhaps another with attributes). This is not primarily in order to prevent XSS, but to remove ugly HTML.

Currently I see no way to do it on the server, so I guess it must be done in JavaScript.

### Current ideas

I found the [jquery-clean plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/), but as far as I can see, it is using regexes to do the work, and [we know that is not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

As I've not found any other JS-based solution I've started to impement one myself using jQuery. It would work by creating a jQuery version of the pasted html (`$(pastedHtml)`) and then traverse the resulting tree, removing each element not matching the whitelist by looking at the attribute `tagName`.

### My questions

- Is this any better?
- Can I trust jQuery to represent the pasted
  content well (there may be unmatched
  ending tags and what-have-you)?
- Is there a better solution already that
  I couldn't find?

### Update

This is my current, jQuery-based, solution (verbose and not extensively tested):

```
function clean(element, whitelist, replacerTagName) {
    // Use div if no replace tag was specified
    replacerTagName = replacerTagName || "div";

    // Accept anything that jQuery accepts
    var jq = $(element);    

    // Create a a copy of the current element, but without its children
    var clone = jq.clone();
    clone.children().remove();

    // Wrap the copy in a dummy parent to be able to search with jQuery selectors
    // 1)
    var wrapper = $('<div/>').append(clone);

    // Check if the element is not on the whitelist by searching with the 'not' selector
    var invalidElement = wrapper.find(':not(' + whitelist + ')');

    // If the element wasn't on the whitelist, replace it.
    if (invalidElement.length > 0) {
       var el = $('<' + replacerTagName + '/>'); 
       el.text(invalidElement.text()); 
       invalidElement.replaceWith(el);   
    }

    // Extract the (maybe replaced) element
    var cleanElement = $(wrapper.children().first());

    // Recursively clean the children of the original element and
    // append them to the cleaned element
    var children = jq.children();
    if (children.length > 0) {
        children.each(function(_index, thechild) {
                          var cleaned = clean(thechild, whitelist, replacerTagName);
                          cleanElement.append(cleaned);
                      });
      } 
    return cleanElement;
}
```

I am wondering about some points (see comments in the code);

1. Do I really need to wrap my element in a dummy parent to be able to match it with jQuery's ":not"?
2. Is this the recommended way to create a new node?

Comment: I can't, in a comment, suggest how this might be done server-side, but JS is accessible to the end-user, and we *don't trust the end users.* This *can* be done client-side, but it needs to be checked server-side too.

Comment: @David Thomas: This why I wrote "not primarily in order to prevent XSS", but I see how it applies to my use case too. However, my environment is an existing CMS, and doing it server-side will be much more difficult. It is also worth mentioning that the users of the editor are logged-in employees who have access to changing page content and even the site structure.

Comment: What I mean is that they can create havoc if they want to. I just want to make it harder to make mistakes and easier to do the right thing.

Comment: *ahhh...* well, in which case, client-side's probably fine then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leverage the browser's HTML correcting abilities (e.g. you copy the rich text to the `innerHTML` of an empty `div` and take the resulting DOM tree), the HTML will be guaranteed to be valid (the way it will be corrected is somewhat browser-dependent). Although this is probably done by rich editor anyways.

jQuery's own text-top DOM transform is probably also safe, but definitely slower, so I would avoid it.

Using a whitelist based on the jQuery selector engine might be somewhat tricky because removing an element while preserving its children might make the document invalid, so the browser would correct it by changing the DOM tree, which might confuse a script trying to iterate through invalid elements. (E.g. you allow `ul` and `li` but not `ol`; the script removes the list root element, naked `li` elements are invalid so the browser wraps them in `ul` again, that `ul` will be missed by the cleaning script.) If you throw away unwanted elements together with all their children, I don't see any problems with that.

Comment: thanks! You are raising an issue I didn't even think of. I have updated my question with the source code of my current solution, where I haven't taken into account what you are saying. When I run my function it does return HTML which is not valid (I have tried your example by allowing li but replacing ul with for example div) and I can add it to the DOM. This is with Chromium in Ubuntu. I'll have to look how it works in other browsers too.

Comment: about jQuery performace... if jQuery isn't extremely slow (and I don't think so), I doubt the user will notice when she is pasting HTML into the editor text area.