# Append html to jQuery element without running scripts inside the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have written some code that takes a string of html and cleans away any ugly HTML from it using jQuery (see an early prototype in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337809/is-it-wise-to-use-jquery-for-whitelisting-tags-are-there-existing-solutions-in-j)). It works pretty well, but I stumbled on an issue:

When using .append() to wrap the html in a div, all script elements in the code are evaluated and run (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element/3603496#3603496) for an explanation why this happens). I don't want this, I really just want them to be removed, but I can handle that later myself as long as they are not run.

I am using this code:

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').append($(html));
```

I tried to do it this way instead:

```
var wrapper = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
```

But that just brings forth the "Access denied" error in IE that the append() function fixes (see the answer I referenced above).

I think I might be able to rewrite my code to not require a wrapper around the html, but I am not sure, and I'd like to know if it is possible to append html without running scripts in it, anyway.

### My questions:

- How do I wrap a piece of unknown html
  without running scripts inside it,
  preferably removing them altogether?
- Should I throw jQuery out the window
  and do this with plain JavaScript and
  DOM manipulation instead? Would that help?

### What I am not trying to do:

I am not trying to put some kind of security layer on the client side. I am very much aware that it would be pointless.

### Update: James' suggestion

James suggested that I should filter out the script elements, but look at these two examples (the original first and the James' suggestion):

```
jQuery("<p/>").append("<br/>hello<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('gnu!'); </script>there")
```

keeps the text nodes but writes gnu!

```
jQuery("<p/>").append(jQuery("<br/>hello<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('gnu!'); </script>there").not('script'))`
```

Doesn't write gnu!, but also loses the text nodes.

### Update 2:

James has updated his answer and I have accepted it. See my latest comment to his answer, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>How about removing the scripts first?</strike>

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').append($(html).not('script'));
```

- Create the div container
- Use plain JS to put html into div
- Remove all script elements in the div

<strike>Assuming script elements in the html are not nested in other elements:</strike>

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = html;
$(wrapper).children().remove('script');
```

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = html;
$(wrapper).find('script').remove();
```

This works for the case where html is just text and where html has text outside any elements.

Comment: Good idea, and it almost works, but not quite. The string that I, somewhat carelessly, call html, might contain text outside of tags, and I want that too. See my updated answer for examples.

Comment: Additionally, the "html" might be just text, with no tags, and then jQuery will treat it as a selector if it is sent to $()/jQuery(), according to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: And the `not()` only works if script is not wrapped inside another element.

Comment: This is promising! With a little modification it seems to work for nested scripts too: `jQuery(wrapper).find('script').remove()`. It works in Chrome, now I'll try it in IE (*cringe*)

Comment: The proof of concept works in IE too. Now I'll add it to my real code.

Comment: Hah, turns out this solution does not solve my problem all the way, although it is correct (and I will of course mark it as accepted). The rich text area I get the html-content from suffers from the same problem. So prior to my code, when the user pastes into the rich text area, the scripts are run. I am using HTMLBox, but tinyMCE and other editors I have tried today also have this problem. I tested it on their demo pages.

Comment: Oh, =( sorry to hear about it not working out after all. I don't have much experience working with web WYSIWYG editors. Thanks for the accept anyway!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should remove the `script` elements:</strike>

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').append($(html).remove("script"));
```

**Second attempt:**

node-validator can be used in the browser:
https://github.com/chriso/node-validator

```
var str = sanitize(large_input_str).xss();
```

Alternatively, PHPJS has a strip_tags function (regex/evil based):
http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535

Comment: Try this code: `jQuery("<div/>").append(jQuery("<br/>hello<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('gnu!'); </script>there").remove('script'))`. It still runs the script tag, actually, and removes just one of the text nodes... Interesting...

Comment: Yeah, the script is executed on `$(html)`… It seems the solution would be to remove the script elements with a regex?

Comment: But that is evil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Comment: Yes, you need a real parser, something BIG like json2.js but for removing script tags :-)

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in the html kept executing for me with all the simple methods mentioned here, then I remembered jquery has a tool for this (since 1.8), `jQuery.parseHTML`. There's still a catch, according to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) events inside attributes(i.e. `<img onerror>`) will still run.

This is what I'm using:

```
var $dom = $($.parseHTML(d));
```

$dom will be a jquery object with the elements found