# Replace html part by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem: I need to replace some word on page with needed html. For example:

```
t = $('body').html();
t = t.replace(/Myword/g, '<div></div>');
$('body').html(t);
```

It is working successfully. But... If body contains javascript tag - JS running again.

If I use document.body - it working

```
t = document.body.innerHTML;
t = t.replace(/Myword/g, '<div></div>');
document.body.innerHTML = t;
```

But I am interested in jQuery solution. Maybe you have it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of modifying the entire page html you need to target only those specific elements with the given text

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you provide that with an example?

Comment: please share your html sample and where the text can appear

Comment: @ArunPJohny It can be plain text. Something like '<div><form>...</form>...Many many text...<div>...</div>Myword</div>

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to ignore all the script tags.

```
t = $('body').clone().find("script").remove().end().html();
t = t.replace(/Myword/g, '<div></div>');
$('body').html(t);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eWLkQ/2/)

Comment: I want use my script on 3rd party pages. I think script deleting is not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution might help you.](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2013/02/javascript-how-to-prevent-execution-of-javascript-within-a-html-being-added-to-the-dom/)

JavaScript not executed if:

1. JavaScript inside the `<script type=”text/xml”>` doesn’t execute
2. JavaScript inside the `<script type=”text/xml” type=”text/javascript”>` doesn’t execute as well because only the first type is considered

so change type:

```
function preventJS(html) {
     return html.replace(/<script(?=(\s|>))/i, '<script type="text/xml" ');
}
```

and use it:

```
t = $('body').html();
t = t.replace(/Myword/g, '<div></div>');
$('body').html(preventJS(t));
```

Comment: I think you are trying to put `<tag>` in your text and it is getting interpreted and hidden from view, so your first bullet points aren't clear. try putting back ticks around the tags.

Comment: Hm. I need to check it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As Arun mentioned in the comments, you should target the elements more specifically. It sounds like `<script>` tags will be re-evaluated if you use JQuery to get the entire `<body>` content and then re-insert it. Try wrapping the desired content in a `<div>`:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>Text that will be altered</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //javascript code
    </script>
</body>
```

Then your code that will replace text can be:

```
t = $('#wrapper').html();
t = t.replace(/Myword/g, '<div></div>');
$('#wrapper').html(t);
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase that to make it clear that capturing the entire content of `<body>` is a requirement.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5550633/1530115) is asking the same thing, and they are discussing some other options there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to just replace `"Myword"` in the most specific element possible. This will only replace `Myword` in the textNodes which contain it and nowhere else.

```
var each = Array.prototype.forEach;

var $myword = $(":contains('Myword')");
$myword.each(function() {
    each.call(this.childNodes, function(ele) {
        if(ele.nodeType === 3 && ele.nodeValue.indexOf('Myword') >= 0) {//if ele is a text node and contains myword
            ele.nodeValue = ele.nodeValue.replace(/Myword/g, "some text");
        } 
    }, this);
});
```

Try running it on this page

Comment: But if I have two and more divs with "Myword" - it replace only one (last) occurrence

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that - you could do a filter to correct that if you wanted