# How to replace a <p> tag in an html file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In an Html file that I have, there is a paragraph tag that basically looks like this:

```
<p class="col-sm-8 form-control-static wordwrap">
Hey
What's
Up
</p>
```

The contents of this paragraph are grabbed from a textarea that a user fills out and the value of this textarea is grabbed via jquery and filled into this element.
The output looks like this: `Hey What's Up`

This paragraph tag ignores the newlines within the paragraph, so the paragraph displays all on one line. Due to the format and layout of the project, I can't necessarily change the html source. I was wondering if there was a way to change this exact element to be:

```
<pre class="col-sm-8 form-control-static wordwrap">
 Hey
 What's
 Up
</pre>
```

using only javascript. Is this possible? This is so my output will keep the newlines.

Comment: use `<pre>` tags

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just style it using CSS `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: `document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = "Hey<br>What's<br>Up";`

Comment: I don't think replacing a paragraph tag with a pre tag is really want you want. Would it be preferrable to still use a paragraph tag but still have it respect your newlines? because that's doable with css (as noted above)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. you tagged jquery so I used that but this could be done in vanilla js too.

I linked to a [`onkeyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event if you wanted to change to use the button only if you wanted

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function updateContent() {
     $('#p1').html($('#source').val());
  }

  $('#update').on('click', function(e){
   updateContent();
   // add other stuff here
   // for only the click event
  })
  
  $('#source').on('keyup', updateContent);


})
```

```css
button {
  display:block;
}

#source {
  height:100px;
}
#p1{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="source" placeholder="Update content and click 'update'">new content

add line breaks and <p>html markup</p>
</textarea>
<button id="update" >Update</button>

<p id="p1">THIS WILL CHANGE!</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple and has been asked before... BUT here it is, using DOM:

```js
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "<p>This</p><p>Has</p><p>Changed!</p>";
```

```html
<p id="p1">THIS WILL CHANGE!</p>
```

So your piece of code you need is:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

**EDIT**

This is simpler, easier and more browser friendly than using `<pre>` tags. Therefore, I would highly recommend you to use this instead.

Comment: There we go that's better!

Comment: *"and has been asked before"* then question should be dupe closed. Do you have a duplicate?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918544/replace-html-part-by-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618470/javascript-replace-html-using-innerhtml). This doesn't end!

Comment: WHY THE DOWNVOTING. ARE YOU GUYS MAD?? Who downvotes the right and only answer?

Comment: i mean... the question specifically asks how to replace a paragraph tag with a preformatted text tag. your answer changes the innerhtml of a paragraph tag and doesn't note why that's better than doing what they wanted to do.